# sendmail - with the same from and to host names

Tags: linux, perl, unix, sendmail

I'm using sendmail in a perl script, and would like to get the "To" address from the user who invoked the script.

In other words I would like the from and to address to be same. How do I do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you currently use `sendmail` to send a message where the to and from addresses are different?

Comment: `open(Mail, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
print MAIL "To: $to\n"
print MAIL $msg
close(MAIL)`

I'm currently entering the my own email in the to address manually
What I need is, if a user invokes this script , he should receive an email once the script completes

Answer (score 0):

Given your code of

```
open(Mail, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t");
print MAIL "To: $to\n"
print MAIL $msg
close(MAIL)
```

I'll suggest adding in front of that

```
$to ||= $ENV{SUDO_USER} || $ENV{USERNAME} || $ENV{LOGNAME} || $ENV{USER} || getpwuid $<;
```

While I'm at it, I'll recommend you add an extra newline after your last header, so that if $msg just happens to start with something that might look like a header, it won't be used as a header.  Unless that's actually behavior you're depending on... (But I'd recommend not depending on that behavior...)

Answer (score -1):

There's not really an "email address" property of a user. If you're just going through a local MTA, the user's address is generally their username, which you can retrieve with `scalar getpwuid $>` on Unixlike systems.